# How to change color of outliers in seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, outliers

I wanna identify the outliers by changing them into another colour from the rest, so that after removing the outliers, the change in scatterplot is clearer.

```
# TotalBsmtSF: Total square feet of basement area

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
b = sns.scatterplot(x = 'TotalBsmtSF', y = 'SalePrice', data = df, ax=ax1,)
plt.title ('Total square feet of basement area VS SalePrice (With Outliers)', fontsize=13)
plt.tight_layout()

# Removing houses with total basement area which is more than 3000 square feet
df = df.drop(df[(df['TotalBsmtSF']>3000) & (df['SalePrice']>=160000)].index)
# print(df['TotalBsmtSF'].head(450))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
b = sns.scatterplot(x = 'TotalBsmtSF', y = 'SalePrice', data = df, ax=ax2,)
plt.title ('Total square feet of basement area VS SalePrice (Outliers Removed)', fontsize=13)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.close(2)
plt.close(3)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn allows you to [change the color](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) of the markers based on categorical or numerical data. So you could create a new column that defines whether the data point is an outlier or not and then call the `hue` parameter in seaborn. These would be the lines to add or change in your code

```
df['outlier'] = np.where(df['TotalBsmtSF']>3000) & (df['SalePrice']>=160000), 'yes', 'no')
b = sns.scatterplot(x = 'TotalBsmtSF', y = 'SalePrice', data = df, ax=ax1, hue="outlier")
```

I think this should work, but I can't confirm since I don't have data to work with